# Write text in DropDownlist without creating new item

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a DropDownlist with 5 items. I want to write in DropDownlist "Select" at the start, make it disappear when DropDownlist is opened and never show it again.
I managed to do it by adding new item and delete it, but is there a way to do it without using Item.Add(new ListItem.....)?

Also I tried to disable new item (it also will be fine) but it completely hide "Select", and I need to see it unless I click on DropDownlist.

```
$('#<%=ddl.ClientID%>').focus(function() {           
        var hasValue = '<%=IfHasValue()%>';        
        if (hasValue == 'True')
        {
            if(!removed){
                var index = $('#<%=ddl.ClientID%>').get(0).selectedIndex;
                $('#<%=ddl.ClientID%> option:eq('+index+')').remove();
                removed = true;
            }
        }
```

This code is working but dropdownlist didn't want to open on first click (when item are deleting), I should click again to open it and see if item is deleted or not (it is).

Can you give me some advise please?

P.S sorry for my bad English.

Comment: If you apply the attributes `disabled` and `selected` to your ListItem then the behaviour you are looking for should be the result. No other way to override the DropDownList, which is why I almost never use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all declare your drop down with AppendDataBoundItems as true:

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddl" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="[ Select ]" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:dropdownlist>
```

Now do your binding normally in code-behind. Once the page is rendered, it will have the "select" option as the first option.

Now, bind the "click" event on the dropdown using jQuery or Javascript:

```
$('#ddl').click(function() {
    // Either pre-select the next option before removing
    //$("#ddl")[0].selectedIndex = 1;

    $("#ddl option[value='0']").remove();

    // Or select the next option after removal 
    $("#ddl")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
});
```

This will remove the "select" option (value "0"). On every click it will try to remove an option with value "0". First time, it will find it and remove. Subsequent times, it won't find any such option and hence won't do anything.

Make sure you provide a unique value to this particular option.

**Edit**:

Alternatively: You can bind "focus" so that this removal happens before mouse-button up is registered thru click.

```
$('#ddl').focus(function() {
    $("#ddl")[0].selectedIndex = 1;
    $("#ddl option[value='0']").remove();
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kne6K

Make sure you pre-select the next option first.

Comment: Thank for answer:) The problem is - I already done it and it works perfectly, but there a moment. When I click on dropdownlist, it remove "Select" BUT also it NOT open dropdownlist for new item selecting, and I need to click again (I have all needed protection to not remove item again). This is the one of the reasons why I asked for help...

Comment: I have updated the answer. You may pre-select the next option before removal or select the first option after removal.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of binding to "click" you may bind "focus", so that removal happens before click is registered.

Comment: +1 for focus, this should work. Or does it get also focus if you are only with the mouse over the control ?

Comment: No focus will only fire when you (1) tab into it, (2) tab out of an element preceding it, (3) click it. When you click it, focus will fire first and then click (mousedown+mouseup). Hover (mouseover) will not fire focus.

Comment: Well, focus made it look much prettily (now I don't have any yanks) but problem still is not solved, dropdown still not opened on first click.

Comment: That is strange. Is "AutoPostBack" set to "true"? That could cause problems.

Comment: Or if AutoPostBack is true do a return false; ?

Comment: I think if it was PostBack then it would simply refresh all items in dropdownlist (I need to fill it in .cs). Well, I tried set AutoPostBack to false... nothing happen O.o

Comment: Hmmm.. well it is difficult to troubleshoot this. Check my fiddle, it is working fine. So, it must perhaps be a different cause altogether unrelated.

Comment: Just to be sure, are there any other click / change handlers defined in JavaScript? Or thru RegisterClientScript from code-behind.

Comment: Maybe it is because I am adding Select at dropdownlist end... (because I have only few situations when I should add this item)... As about fiddler, yes it is working and I am envying :(

Comment: No, there no another click/change event in Javascript, and I am not using RegisterClientScrip...  I will try to add example to  my question

Comment: It is difficult to say anything without looking at your code.

Comment: Open up console and see if any javascript errors are logged there. Also, you are not pre-selecting the next option before removal.

Comment: I checked and there no javascript errors... Do I need to pre-select need item? (After item deleting it automatically select first item) If  I need to, can I select value using this:  $('#<%=ddl.ClientID%>').val('0');  (first element value) or is there any other way to select first item?

Comment: See my answer, add this just before you remove: `$("#ddl")[0].selectedIndex = 1;` i.e. before your `$('#<%=ddl.ClientID%> option:eq('+index+')').remove();` line. Better still, just copy-paste the code in my answer.

Comment: Can we see it in action? Some link?

Comment: I am afraid not... but... anyway, thank for trying to help me:)

Answer (score 0):

So you can, if you load it, replace your first item with select.
After you load the special values into your DDL do this:

```
Session["ReplacedItem"] = DropDownList.Items[0].Text; // Store your old Text here
DropDownList.Items[0].Text = "Select";
```

Then add the OnClick function:

```
DropDownList.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return ChangeTextBack()")
```

Then in your aspxcode add this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function ChangeTextBack() {

var RI = '<%= Session["ReplacedItem"].ToString() %>';var 
select=document.getElementById("DropDownList1");
select.options[0].text=RI;
return false;

}
```

Comment: I managed to click on DropDownlist with jQuery help:) Thank for answer but it will be bad for me if I make some changes in Items, even if it is only text.

Comment: Why is it bad if you change your text ? Cant you store it in a Session, change the Text, and change it back then ?
With Javascript you could add a function to change it back on the OnClick event. OnClick event can be registered like: `DropDownList.Attributes.Add("onclick", "function")`

Comment: I have a generated text in each Item and special values. I will get new problem then (how to restore all data in item).

Comment: Thats why i store it in a `Session` first. Then you can have the Text back.

Answer (score 0):

add new item at the beginning of the `options` collection of dropdownlist on client when page is loaded, and in `onchange` event check if this item exists in the collection, then remove it.

you can get DropDownlist on client using `$get("<%= DropDowwnlist.ClentID%>")`

Comment: Already done it. I asked for different solution :( But thank for answer.